# Django forms 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

the error is with the following:

registerform = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
Error here!if registerform.is_valid():

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': ("The two password fields didn't match."),
        "email_missing": ("Please enter email."),
        "name_missing": ("Please enter name."),
    }
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=("Password"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Repeat Password'}),
        help_text=("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label=("First Name"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label=("Last Name"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last name'}))
    username = forms.CharField(label=("Username"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'}))
    
    email = forms.EmailField(label=("Email"), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}),help_text=('Security is of upmost importance for Glocal. We require email address verification in order to prevent trolling and fake accounts. Please enter your email address below and click on "verify" in the email that we will send you, in order to activate your account.'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(UserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        # remove username
        self.fields.pop('username')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email",)

    field_order = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2', 'email']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserCreationForm, self).clean()
        password1 = cleaned_data["password1"]
        password2 = cleaned_data["password2"]
        email = cleaned_data["email"]
        username = cleaned_data['first_name'] + "." + cleaned_data['last_name']
        first_name = cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = cleaned_data['last_name']
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        if not email:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['email_missing'],
                code="email_missing")
        if not first_name or not last_name:
            raise forms.ValidationError( self.error_messages['name_missing'], code="name_missing")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

I'm not sure what's wrong here. The failure is something to do with the .is_valid() routine, even though the form shows up as valid.

```
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py, line 181, in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
Local vars
/Users/adenhandasyde/GitHub/Googlocal/Glocal/views.py, line 1178, in registrations_new
        if registerform.is_valid(): …
Local vars
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py, line 190, in is_valid
        return self.is_bound and not self.errors …
Local vars
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py, line 185, in errors
            self.full_clean() …
Local vars
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py, line 406, in full_clean
        self._post_clean() …
Local vars
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/models.py, line 392, in _post_clean
        exclude = self._ge
t_validation_exclusions() …
Local vars
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/forms/models.py, line 352, in _get_validation_exclusions
                field_value = self.cleaned_data.get(field) …
Local vars
```

There's something here on line 352 about a django form model.

self.cleaned_data might be returning a string.

Thank you, 'return cleaned_data' rather than 'return password2'

Comment: Please include the full error traceback message.

Comment: `def clean` should be returning your `cleaned_data` not your password